# Saving Backbone.js model data. Data not sent correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js and I'm trying to save a model instance.
I'm using django as my server.

Client side Code:

```
var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'New Song'
    },
    url: function() {
        return window.location.href;
    }

});

var song = new Song()
song.save()
```

`csrfmiddlewaretoken` is set properly before the data is sent.

I stepped through the jQuery $.ajax function called internally by 
Backbone.sync and found that the model object contains the correct data.

However, the `request.POST` received by the server is

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'[object Object]': [u'']}>
```

instead of the actual data. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

**Update:** I did a quick fix by setting `Backbone.emulateJSON` to true. But according to the comments in the Backbone (0.9.2) code it is meant for legacy servers. I'm using Django 1.4.1. Does it mean django 1.4.1 is incompatible?

**Update 2**: When I set `Backbone.emulateJSON` to `false`, I get the following error in firefox but it fails silently in chrome.

```
   "[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80460001 
(NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA)"  nsresult: "0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA)"

  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:8000/static/jquery.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 8214"  data: no]"
```

I'm using jQuery for ajax as preferred by Backbone and it seems the error might be in jQuery.

**Update 3**: I solved it by overriding the $.ajax used by Backbone.sync with my own. It is still a quick fix.

Backbone.js verson: 0.9.2

jQuery version: 1.8.0. Also tried with 1.7.2. Same result.

Comment: Can you look at your network panel and see the data that is being posted to your server. I am not familiar with Django, but your problem definitely looks like a server side issue and not an issue with Backbone.

Comment: @TyroneMichael Thanks for the suggestion. The network panel in chrome shows that the model is sent as a plain Object in Request Payload. But in firefox I got the error written in Update 2.

Comment: I dont think the data is being send as a string (Take a look [here](http://communities.rightnow.com/posts/9580c78607)). Do you get this error when Emulate JSON is false? What happens in FF when you comment out Emulate JSON = false?

Comment: @Pramod: Check out solution posted [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204018/saving-backbone-js-model-data-data-not-sent-correctly/25731259#25731259). Its possible to override Backbone.sync to get the model data in the request.POST QueryDict.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having a similar issue and through some detective work/luck I figured it out. The issue is that by default Backbone sends the POST data as a JSON encoded string in the body of the request not as a part of the `request.POST` QueryDict. So to get the data in this case you would have to use the python json library and call `json.loads(request.body)` in the Django view to read the data properly.

As an aside, the reason that setting `Backbone.emulateJSON = true;` works is because then Backbone sends the JSON to Django through the "legacy" mechanism which makes it appear in the `request.POST` QueryDict.

Comment: ...or `json.loads(request.raw_post_data)` for older versions of django

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data to be available in the QueryDict request.POST, then you will have to override the Backbone.sync method.

First of all you will have to set Backbone.emulateJSON to true.

You can have a look at the Backbone.sync method over [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1201). You will notice that the model attributes are stringified.

```
if (options.data == null && model && (method === 'create' || method === 'update' || method === 'patch')) {
  params.contentType = 'application/json';
  params.data = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON(options));
}
```

Edit this part of the function to:

```
if (options.data == null && model && (method === 'create' || method === 'update' || method === 'patch')) {
  params.contentType = 'application/json';
  if(options.emulateJSON){
     params.data = options.attrs || model.toJSON(options);
  }else{
     params.data = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON(options));
  }
}
```

On some other line you will notice that Backbone adds a 'model' key to the POST QueryDict.

```
params.data = params.data ? {model: params.data} : {};
```

Edit this line to:

```
params.data = params.data ? params.data : {};
```

Thats it! Now you will have the data as a part of request.POST QueryDict.